# Move spaces from inside tags to outside

Tags: javascript

I am getting a response from an API of this form:

```
'some thing here <span class="text-underline"> foo </span>bar'
```

I want to remove spaces from inside the span to avoid weird looking formatting, and move them out.

This is my current implementation. Is there a better way to do this?

```js
const sanitize = _data => {
  let outputData = _data.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ').replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');

  const rotR = (s, l, r) =>
    s.substring(0, l) + s[r] + s.substring(l, r) + s.substr(r + 1);

  const rotL = (s, l, r) =>
    s.substring(0, l) + s.substring(l + 1, r + 1) + s[l] + s.substr(r + 1);

  [...outputData.matchAll(/<[^/^>]+> /g)].forEach(match => {
    outputData = rotR(
      outputData,
      match.index,
      match.index + match[0].length - 1
    );
  });

  [...outputData.matchAll(/ <\/[^>]+>/g)].forEach(match => {
    outputData = rotL(
      outputData,
      match.index,
      match.index + match[0].length - 1
    );
  });

  return outputData.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
};

console.log(sanitize('some thing here <span class="text-underline"> foo </span>bar'))
```

---

Edit: This function is running on server side (`node.js` backend) before data is being stored in the database. I can't interact with DOM directly. Data returned by the API is a `string`, not an HTML document.

Comment: Moving space outside might have consequences that you didn’t expect: in your example, moving the left whitespace out to before the span tag will mean there will be two consecutive whitespace characters. That will be collapsed into a single whitespace.

Comment: @Terry How is that a problem? _...That will be collapsed into a single whitespace...._ Well, this is a desired effect for me, I am doing `.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')` explicitly.

Comment: Never said it’s a problem. Just an FYI LOL.

Comment: I would first try to fix the issue at its source. First, I would report a bug to the API author(s) to get it fixed in the API instead. If that is not possible, I would try to find another solution and avoid that API altogether. Meanwhile, I would just keep the current API output. If somebody would complain about the rendered result, I would tell them that "the issue is known and under investigation" and refer to the API and its author(s). Only as a last resort, and only if this issue is *really* important, I would "fix" this issue in my own code as an (unmaintained) temporary workaround.

Comment: So I am just saying that if your code works as desired, just use it. Don't spend more time on it than it deserves.

Comment: @BartHofland Noted man! :)

Comment: By the way, I am sorry if I am too direct or too harsh. That's not my intention. It's just my humble opinion and I cannot judge your circumstances. Just be careful that you do not end up making patches that hide such issues. In the end, it could make your solution unnecessarily fragile or slow.

Answer (score 0):

Have a go with this. You should not use regexp to parse HTML

On NODE you can add a dom parser

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom

```js
const str = 'some thing here <span class="text-underline"> foo </span>bar';

const div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = str;
const output = document.createElement("div");
const parts = [...div.childNodes].map(ele => {
  console.log(ele.textContent, ele.nodeType);
  if (ele.nodeType === 1) {
    const eleStr = ele.textContent;
    const start = eleStr.match(/^(\s+)/)?.[1];
    const end = eleStr.match(/(\s+)$/)?.[1]
    ele.textContent = eleStr.trim();
    if (start) output.appendChild(document.createTextNode(start))
    output.appendChild(ele)
    if (end) output.appendChild(document.createTextNode(end))
  }
  else output.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ele.textContent))
  output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' '); // this should be safe enough
})
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but my function is running on server side (node.js backend) before data is being stored in the database. I can't currently interact with DOM directly. (Added that in the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function sanitize(str) {
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = str;
  Array.from(span.querySelectorAll("span")).forEach(function(span) {
    string = str.split(span.innerHTML);
    string[0] = string[0].replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
    string[1] = string[1].replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
    if (span.innerHTML[0] == " " || span.innerHTML[0] == "&nbsp;") {
      span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML.substr(1)
      string[0] = string[0] + " ";
    }
    if (span.innerHTML.slice(-1) == " " || span.innerHTML.slice(-1) == "&nbsp;") {
      span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML.substr(0, span.innerHTML.length - 1)
      string[1] = " " + string[1];
    }
    console.log(String(string[0] + span.innerHTML + string[1]));
  });
}
console.log(sanitize('some thing here<span class="text-underline"> foo </span>bar'))
```